# git svn fetch became slow (up to 30 seconds waiting before every revision fetch)

Tags: git, git-svn

after some system reconfiguration on my new Ubuntu 10.10 `git svn fetch` became very slow waiting for up to 30 seconds every time it is trying to get a new svn revision.

I am using `git-svn version 1.7.1 (svn 1.6.12)`

It fetches the files of the revision normally fast, but then waits very long to get the next revision. On other machines git svn fetching from the same SVN repository is working blazingly fast as it used to do just some days before on my machine.

I dropped `auth` folder in the `~/.subverion`. I reinstalled all packages that related to git and to subversion including libraries. It does not help.

So I did some `strace`, when it fetches revisions, and waits, I can see in the process tree something like this:

```
 % ps fxx | egrep '(git|svn)'
 5154 pts/0    S+     0:00  |   \_ strace -fc git svn fetch
 5155 pts/0    t+     0:00  |       \_ git svn fetch
 5156 pts/0    tL+    0:00  |           \_ /usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn fetch
 5217 pts/0    S+     0:00  |               \_ git hash-object -w --stdin-paths --no-filters
 5219 pts/0    S+     0:00  |               \_ git cat-file --batch
 5253 pts/0    S+     0:00  |               \_ git update-ref -m r75 refs/remotes/trunk 8a79cacd6d3c36eb338f6ed5f23269a163600d0f
```

and the output of the `strace` is something like:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 59.28    0.048312         156       309           waitpid
 39.99    0.032594         104       313           clone
  0.18    0.000149           0      7443      3296 access
  0.11    0.000088           0      5936       692 open
  0.09    0.000071           0      2285           munmap
  0.06    0.000046           0       228           send
  0.05    0.000040           0      5761           read
  0.04    0.000036           0      1962           brk
  0.04    0.000032           0      4366           fstat64
  0.04    0.000031           0      1304           write
  0.03    0.000021           0      6972           close
  0.02    0.000019           0      6502           mmap2
  0.02    0.000015           0       131           recvfrom
  0.01    0.000012           0       335           pipe
  0.01    0.000011           0       863           recv
  0.01    0.000010           0      1662       636 stat64
  0.01    0.000009           0       894           fcntl64
```

so what kind of `waitpid` it is doing? I want my fast `git-svn` back :)

Comment: Just a guess: maybe git svn gc could help you? Although it should be run automatically, I think, it's worth a try...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as expected, it was an issue with DNS and name resolutions.

What I did yesterday, is that I changed the networking configuration to get fetch only IP address from the DHCP and set search domains and DNS servers myself. Everything worked fine so far, but the git-svn

Doing more strace I noticed, that it was trying to use some a host name, that I changed a week ago, and the only place, where it could have taken it was the DNS. After resetting network connection to get everything from the DHCP server again, the issue with git-svn disappeared.

Ok, now I cannot use the DNS search paths as I want it, but at least git-svn started to work again.

Probably I have to play a little bit with the `/etc/hosts` to set the local IP to have the name of my host to ease up the reverse lookups...